# ValueError: Cannot assign "[<CustomUser: User1>]": "Table1.userID" must be a "CustomUser" instance

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, axios

```html
class Table1(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    Department = models.CharField("Department", max_length=100, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    userID = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
```

I am trying to post the form_data via axios but this ValueError keeps coming. Also if I send the same data in json form it accepts but not in form_data.

trying to execute this:

```
obj, create = Table1.objects.update_or_create(userID=request.user, defaults= data)
```

Here : `data` is `request.data.copy()`

I need to post this in form_data cause I'm uploading images. Kindly help.

```html
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def table1_list(request):
      data=request.data.copy()
      data['userID'] = request.user
      print(data)

      obj, create = Table1.objects.update_or_create(userID=request.user, defaults= data)
      id = obj.id
      res = {
          "id": id,
      }
      return Response(res, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Please share your `Table1` model, and the entire view.

Comment: class Table1(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    Department = models.CharField("Department", max_length=100, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    userID = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make much sense to pass the `userID` both as parameter to `update_or_create` and as `defaults=`. Furthermore by using `request.data.copy()` will make another `QueryDict`, but a `QueryDict` is a collection that maps strings to *lists* of values, so not a single value.

You thus likely want to work with:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def table1_list(request):

      obj, create = Table1.objects.update_or_create(
          userID=request.user,
          defaults=request.data.dict()
      )
      id = obj.id
      res = {
          'id': id,
      }
      return Response(res, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I would however advise making use of a *serializer* to convert the data into a model object. Here we do not do any verification if the data makes sense.

Comment: If I have one more foreign key in table1 (let's say from Table2) then I can't use request.user. What to do then?

Comment: @Durgendra: first create a `Table2` object, or look it up in the database, and then pass it with `update_or_create(userID=request.user, my_foreignkey=table2_instance, defaults=request.data.dict())`